# Nullable Property with protected setter, inferred as Friend(Internal) Field

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
class Program
{
    public class Test
    {
        private Test() { }

        public Test(string name, int? code)
        {
            Name = name;
            Code = code;
        }
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public int? Code { get; protected set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test("Vahid", 10);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When you run the above-mentioned code, you will see that `t.Code` is inferred as FriendField(Internal), but as we can see it is a Public Property!

Does anybody know the reason?

[image]

Comment: Why are you worried about that symbol? That's only VS's debugger

Comment: This is a known VS bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/232694/public-nullable-property-in-public-class-shows-as.html

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am not worry about it, it was just interesting for me to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved. Here is the comment by Microsoft community:

> A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent
>   release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ . Thank you
>   for providing valuable feedback which has helped improve the product.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is a Friend field, I have never heard that this notion exists in C# so I assume it really does not.

You have a definition of both Name and Code as a property (since you have get and set). This is a definition of property.

So it is perhaps the GUI that is showing it wrong.

If you want to ensure what it really is you can use reflection:

```
t.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it is a GUI bug, and every thing is OK behind the scene.